# Need to Extract only keys present in the JSON schema

Tags: javascript, json

```
  {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
       "header" : {
         "type" : "object",
         "properties" : {
            "outType" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "id" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "application" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "userId" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
         }
       }
    }
```

In the above snippet i only want the keys. I am iterating a variable through the object properties which is giving me only "type" & "properties". But I want all the keys present in nested objects. Recursion is the only solution to this. But failing in applying the logic to the above snippet.
How can I identify that the value of a particular key is again an object..??

I am try it with this above function, is that correct?

```
function traverse(myObj) {
  for (x in myObj) {
    if typeof myObj[x] == 'string'
    then print(x);
    else traverse(myObj[x])
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (Object(currentItem) === currentItem)` will tell you whether or not something is an object

Comment: function traverse(myObj)
 {for(x in myObj){
  if typeof myObj[x] == 'string'
  then print(x);
  else
  traverse(myObj[x])
  }
 }
i am trying like this with the above function?? is that correct

Comment: @VibhavKushwaha please use the `edit` button if you want to add more details to the question. Pasting code in the comment is not helpful because it is not readable.

Comment: Do you want all keys, or only the keys where the value is an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`reviver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) callback of `JSON.parse` to collect the keys at the time when you parse your json string:

```js
var keys = [];
var json = '{"type":"object","properties":{"header":{"type":"object","properties":{"outType":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"},"application":{"type":"string"},"userId":{"type":"string"}}}}}';
var data = JSON.parse(json, function(key, value) {
  // if the key exists and if it is not in the list then add it to the array
  if (key 
      // && typeof value === 'object'  //only required if you only want the key if the value is an object
      && keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
    keys.push(key);
  }

  //return the original value so that the object will be correctly created
  return value;
});

console.log(keys);
console.dir(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion helped me.