# Parse Key Values from Json to build in Array

Tags: arrays, json, object, parsing, indexing

I am trying to take the key values of a JSON such as the areaID, and areaUUID and build into an array, such that the array looks like this ["areaID","areaUUID","areaName"...]. I don't want the values of the json.

[
    {
        "areaID": 37,
        "areaUUID": "eef6126a-14fa-4400-a6ba-c4f19704a168",
        "areaName": "HF CALCIUM SULFATE (CALSUL)",
        "plantID": 7,
        "plantUUID": "bcb4c79c-9bd7-4929-a013-0828972e1e88",
        "plantName": "LaPorte",
        "underConstruction": "",
        "subsiteID": 0,
        "positionLeft": 0,
        "positionTop": 0,
        "drawingID": 0,
        "createdBySiteID": 1,
        "modifiedBySiteID": 1,
        "recordLastUpdated": "2015-01-12T21:19:28.145",
        "portalActive": 1,
        "csidbuid": "",
        "csiAreaKey": 0,
        "lineFrequency": 1
    }

Answer (score 0):

### I have found this solution for you

Source  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42840748/9231356

```
var keys = [];
var json = '{"type":"object","properties":{"header":{"type":"object","properties":{"outType":{"type":"string"},"id":{"type":"string"},"application":{"type":"string"},"userId":{"type":"string"}}}}}';
var data = JSON.parse(json, function(key, value) {
  // if the key exists and if it is not in the list then add it to the array
  if (key 
      // && typeof value === 'object'  //only required if you only want the key if the value is an object
      && keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
    keys.push(key);
  }

  //return the original value so that the object will be correctly created
  return value;
});

console.log(keys);
console.dir(data);
```

Hope it can help you!